# How to handle video intent broadcast by system

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I'm developing a video player app and i want to register my app as video player so when user tap on video, my app should also be shown in "choose app" list. So my  **first question is that how to register my app** and when user choose my app so **how do I extract video information from intent so I can handle it properly(I mean playing it).**

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional `intent-filter` to your launcher activity with mimeType `video/*` like below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

And inside your activity's `onCreate` handle the intent and play video like below:

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

videoView.setVideoURI(getIntent().getData());
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.seekTo(1);
```